# How to pass values between ViewModels using Caliburn.micro EventAggregator MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I am trying to understand and implement EventAggregator using Caliburn micro. I am a new student of MVVM.
My goal: I want to create a window/popup that will be used to update customers. I want to make it possible to update customers from different usercontrols using the same window. I could be completely off the mark here, so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

My Event Class:

```
    private CustomerModel _selectedCustomer;

    public SelectedCustomerEvent(CustomerModel selectedCustomer)
    {
        _selectedCustomer = selectedCustomer;
    }

    public CustomerModel SelectedCustomer { get { return _selectedCustomer; } }
```

My Popup/Window used to update a customer:

```
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    public CustomerUpdateViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
    {
        _events = events;
        _events.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(SelectedCustomerEvent message)
    {
        Customer = message.SelectedCustomer;
    }

    public CustomerModel Customer { get; private set; }
```

One of the UserControls that will open the window to update a customer:

```
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    public CustomerViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
    {
        _events = events;
        _events.Subscribe(this);
    }
    ..........
    private CustomerModel _selectedCustomer;
    public CustomerModel SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _selectedCustomer; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCustomer = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedCustomer);
            _events.PublishOnUIThread(new SelectedCustomerEvent(SelectedCustomer));
        }
    }

    public void UpdateCustomer()
    {
        WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
        CustomerUpdateViewModel cn = new CustomerUpdateViewModel();
        wm.ShowWindow(cn);
    }
```

My issue right now is that I get an error on "new CustomerUpdateViewModel()" that says: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'events' of CustomerUpdateViewModel(IEventAggregator).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It wasnt a problem with the eventaggregator, but with the navigation. I needed to put the WindowManager and the ViewModel in the constructor like so:

```
  public CustomerViewModel(IEventAggregator events, IWindowManager windowManager, CustomerUpdateViewModel customerUpdateVM)
    {
        _windowManager = windowManager;
        _customerUpdateVM = customerUpdateVM;

        _events = events;
        _events.Subscribe(this);
    }
```

and change the method to open the window:

```
public void UpdateCustomer() => _windowManager.ShowDialog(_customerUpdateVM);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, Constructor for CustomerUpdateViewModel requires a parameter of type `IEventAggregator`. This is missing in the code.

Constructor of `CustomerUpdateViewModel`:

```
public CustomerUpdateViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
{
        _events = events;
        _events.Subscribe(this);
}
```

Call to constructor in OP, with argument missing:

```
public void UpdateCustomer()
{
    WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
    CustomerUpdateViewModel cn = new CustomerUpdateViewModel(); // Argument missing
    wm.ShowWindow(cn);
}
```

The way you have fixed it in your own answer was by injecting an instance of `CustomerUpdateViewModel` into the `CustomerViewModel`. This might be an unnecessary step, if for example, you do not navigate to `CustomerUpdateViewModel` every time you display `CustomerViewModel`.

Instead, you could you still use your initial approach and initialize an instance of `CustomerUpdateViewModel` only when you actually need it. You only need to pass an instance of `IEventAggregator` to it.

For example:

```
public void UpdateCustomer()
{
    WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
    CustomerUpdateViewModel cn = new CustomerUpdateViewModel(_events);
    wm.ShowWindow(cn);
}
```